# What is the lowest degree to guarantee a polynomial exists which go through $N$ points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Suppose I have $N$ points $(x_i, y_i)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. What is $D$ such that we can say there exists a degree $D$ polynomial $p$ with real coefficients satisfying $y_i = p (x_i)$ for each of the $N$ points? How do we prove it? Thank you!

Comment: The lowest degree is even $0$. Say $y_i = 1$ and you select N points $(x_i, 1)$ where no two $x_i$ are equal. This means you have to specify more conditions on the points or you have to ask for the "worst case".

Comment: Are you assuming that the $x_i$ are distinct if the $y_i$ are distinct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Degree $N-1$ will do the job, as long as the $x_i$ are distinct. This generalizes "two points determine a line."

See [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: Degree $N-1$ will do the job in all cases, including the worst case (defined as the one which requires the highest degree). Lower degrees are possible in special cases.